# Unable to run git project in android studio

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github, import

I am trying to download and run a photo editing project into android studio. i have tried both ways (1. By clone project and 2. By download project), but always getting same result.(Check attached screenshot).[image]
Project is showing in the Android Studio but Run or Debug button is disabled and also project structure is not like other projects in the project window. I have tried two different git projects facing same problem with both. Link of one of them is here: https://github.com/baugarten/Android-Image-Edit

Let me know what is the problem. Where i am wrong or what is the proper way to download and run git project into Android Studio.

**Note: Please check screenshot to see what i am seeing when download and import project into Android Studio.**

Answer (score 2):

Your project wasn't imported correctly.
https://github.com/baugarten/Android-Image-Edit is eclipse project, you should try "import project (eclipse,ADT...)"

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/baugarten/Android-Image-Edit not Gradle project that's why this error occurs.
so manually clone it and try "import project (eclipse,ADT...)"

Answer (score 0):

I am not, but of what I see you didn't download the entire project from github.

Clone it from the link you gave. Make sure you have all the files of the project before running it.

Can you run a project if you create one on your own?

Answer (score 0):

The project you are trying to clone is not using gradle system.

If your android studio is running press `

File => Close Project => Import Project => Next => Finish.

It will work. And for the future if you don't see gradle files in libraries it means you should import then not just open.